# MVC 4 Uploading Excel file to database

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

Encounter this problem 
'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Files' and no extension method 'Files' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

No idea how to convert the date for this line

user.StudentDob = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 6].Value.ToString();

Anyone can help? trying to upload excel file to read.

This is my Controller

```
public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        if (Request != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];
            if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
            {
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
                var usersList = new List<Student>();
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
                {
                    var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                    var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                    var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                    var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;

                    for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                    {
                        var user = new Student();
                        user.StudentId = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value.ToString().FirstOrDefault();
                        user.StudentNric = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value.ToString();
                        user.StudentName = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Value.ToString();
                        user.StudentContact = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Value.ToString().FirstOrDefault();
                        user.StudentEmail = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 5].Value.ToString();
                        user.StudentDob = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 6].Value.ToString();
                        user.FirstLogin = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 7].Value.ToString();
                        usersList.Add(user);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

This is my Model

```
public partial class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentNric { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int StudentContact { get; set; }
    public string StudentEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTime StudentDob { get; set; }
    public string FirstLogin { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast explicitly the string you receive in the cell to the *DateTime* type, possibly using a Format String that matches the format of the Excel file. For instance if the date in excel comes like *2017-07-18* you will have to do

```
user.StudentDob = DateTime.ParseExact(
                                      workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 6].Value.ToString(),
                                      "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: How about the error for 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Files' and no extension method 'Files' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found.